# How can we store two different parameters in a single array with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to store two parameter of a single user in single array. One is user money that he want to save and the time when he saves his money so this two parameter should be store in array how is it possible. I also want to grab them from the array like when i grab index 0 than it suppose to return me 2 things one the amount he saved and the time when he saved that amount. I am trying with the following code.

```
user_money_to_save =[100,399,4499]
time_save = [0.1,0.2,3.4]
user_data=[user_money_to_save,time_save]

print(user_data[0])#this is returning me user_money_to_save. not [100,0.1]
```

Comment: My first guess is that you make a POST request, but with no/invalid CSRF token: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25954538/67579

Comment: I am not using post method anywhere

Comment: Not the post method. How do you make a HTTP request to the view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem by the way is it necessary to make delete confirm template , can i delete comment by clicking on remove button keep staying of post detail template?

Comment: If you want `user_data[0] == (100, 0.1)`, you need to zip the lists together: `user_data = list(zip(user_money_to_save, time_save))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function which takes iterables (can be zero or more), aggregates them in a tuple, and return it.

```
user_money_to_save =[100,399,4499]
time_save = [0.1,0.2,3.4]

user_data = list(zip(user_money_to_save, time_save))

print(user_data)
```

Output

`[(100, 0.1), (399, 0.2), (4499,3.4)]`